C++ Modules and cmake
I got some code running with modules. Now my question is, is there a way to reuse these precompilations from let's say a library to use it for an application?
In cmake I used this code snippet
target_sources(test_geometry
  PRIVATE
      src/geometry/test_polygons.cpp
      src/geometry/test_buffer.cpp
      src/geometry/test_performance.cpp
  PRIVATE FILE_SET moduleunits TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES ${core_mod_files})
target_link_libraries(test_geometry PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2WithMain)

I would would like to reuse these core_mod_files to compile a different application in a different folder path. Is there a concept where these core_mod_files could be included in something like a archive for reusing on different places?
